# ¿Cómo puedo consultar tomando en cuenta cada filtro con Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla que tiene tres columnas y encima tengo dos filtros, la idea es que si se llena un filtro se muestren los resultados y si se llena el segundo se consulte de acuerdo a lo obtenido con el primer filtro, pero no he logrado hacer que funcione de esa forma, si alguno tiene una solución se lo agradezco.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(filtrar);
        $("#select").change(filtrar);
    })
    const filtrar = () => {
    console.log("true");
    const select = $('#select').val();
    const search = $('#search').val();
    
    let filtrar = false;
    const listFilter = [];
    if(select !== undefined && select.length > 0){
        const res = buscador("#select", 2, true);
        listFilter.push(...res);
        filtrar = true;
    }    
    if(search !== undefined && search !== ("")){
        res = buscador("#search", 0);
        listFilter.push(...res);
        filtrar = true;
    }
    
    if(filtrar){
        $.each($("#registros tbody tr"), function() { $(this).hide() });
        listFilter.forEach(function(item) { $(item).show() });
    }else{
        $.each($("#registros tbody tr"), function() { $(this).show() });
        return;
    }
}

const buscador = (selector, posicion, multiple=false, text=false) => {
    
    _this = $(selector)[0];
    list = [];
    if(multiple){
      for(let i = 0; i < $(_this).val().length; i++){

        const valor = $(_this)[0].selectedOptions[i];
        console.log($(valor).text());
        $.each($("#registros tbody tr"), function() {
          const element = $(this)[0].children[posicion];
            if($(element).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(valor).text().toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            list.push(this);

          }

        });     

      }
    }else{
      $.each($("#registros tbody tr"), function() {
        const element = $(this)[0].children[posicion];
        const valor = text ? $(_this).text() : $(_this).val();
        if($(element).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(valor.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
          
          list.push(this);
        }
      });
    }
    return list;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<script>
    
</script>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<input id="search"/>
<select id="select" multiple>
    <option value="1">Germany</option>
    <option value="2">Mexico</option>
    <option value="3">Austria</option>
    <option value="4">UK</option>
    <option value="5">Canada</option>
    <option value="6">Italy</option>
</select>

<table id="registros">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pido disculpas pero me parecio demasiado complicado tu código. Es por esto que te propongo uno diferente.

- Modificamos la tabla para mover los encabezados al `thead` y los registros al `tbody`
- Modificamos la función `filtrar`:

  - Creamos un objeto donde vamos a guardar los filtros aplicados
  - Recorremos cada una de las filas y verificamos si cada uno de los filtros aplicados coinciden.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(filtrar);
  $("#select").change(filtrar);
})

const filtrar = () => {
  const filters = {};

  // Obtenemos los paises selecionados
  const $countries = $('#select option:selected');
  if ($countries.length > 0) {
    filters.countries = $countries.map(function() {
      return this.innerText.toLowerCase()
    }).get();
  }

  // Obtenemos el valor de search
  const $search = $('#search');
  if ($search.val() !== '') {
    filters.search = $search.val().toLowerCase();
  }

  // Si contiene filtros
  const totalFilters = Object.keys(filters).length;

  // Por cada fila
  $("#registros tr").each(function() {
    let $tr = $(this),
      $childs = $tr.children(),
      matchs = 0;

    // Si se filtro por pais
    if (filters.countries) {
      let text = $childs.get(2).innerText.toLowerCase();
      // Si detectamos alguno de los paises seleccionados
      let found = filters.countries.find(c => text == c);
      if (found !== undefined) matchs++;
    }

    // Si se filtro por empresa
    if (filters.search) {
      let text = $childs.get(0).innerText.toLowerCase();
      // Si incluye la cadena ingresada
      if (text.includes(filters.search)) matchs++;
    }

    // Si TODOS los filtros coinciden
    if (matchs == totalFilters) $tr.show();
    else $tr.hide();
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<input id="search" />
<select id="select" multiple>
  <option value="1">Germany</option>
  <option value="2">Mexico</option>
  <option value="3">Austria</option>
  <option value="4">UK</option>
  <option value="5">Canada</option>
  <option value="6">Italy</option>
</select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="registros">
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Entiendo, sí lo hice un poco más complejo para que fuese más adaptable a cualquier pantalla, pero ya como veo que lo haces intentaré ajustarlo, te agradezco